# Is it possible to have Cloud Firestore in multiple regions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently building a website and am using Firebase as my database. Due to the needs described by my customer, I need to be able to use the website (and have access to the database) in both the US and Europe. As far as I can tell, my two options are as follows:

- Create two projects: I would simply have one project in the US and one in Europe with the same code. The data in the US and Europe will not be the same. This is not preferred as it is not a neat solution.
- Cloud Firestore in multiple regions: Ideally, I would have one collection being hosted in the US, and another in Europe, as the data can and will be different. I would also be ok with having the data being hosted in both the US and Europe.

As I said, my preference would be the second option, is this possible using Cloud FireStore? Or would it be easier to just have two separate projects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option is not possible.  A single project can have a single Firestore instance, it must choose a specific region as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations).  Once you choose this region for a project, it can't be changed.

The only [multi-region configurations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations#location-mr) are actually replicated across zones within a region, and there is no such configuration that spans continents.